# Display scrollable item Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, scroll, uitextview

For my application I have a UITextView, and I need to display an arrow when there's scrollable content.

The image has to been hidden when you're at the bottom or when you can't scroll through text.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

   self.scrollableItem.hidden = YES;
   float scrollViewHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height;
   float scrollContentSizeHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height;
   float scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

   if (scrollOffset > 0 && scrollOffset <= scrollViewHeight / 2) {
    self.scrollableItem.hidden = NO;
   } else if (scrollOffset <= 0 && scrollContentSizeHeight >= scrollViewHeight) {
    self.scrollableItem.hidden = NO;
   }
}
```

For now that works approximatively but I would like to know if there's a more generic way ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track.  We just need a formula to describe the desired condition: there's more text than will fit and that text extends below the bottom of the view

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView != self.textView) return;
    [self updateScrollableItem:(UITextView *)scrollView];
}

- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
    [self updateScrollableItem:textView];
}

- (void)updateScrollableItem:(UITextView *)textView {
    CGSize contentSize = textView.contentSize;
    CGSize boundsSize = textView.bounds.size;
    CGFloat contentOffsetY = textView.contentOffset.y;

    BOOL excess = contentSize.height > boundsSize.height;
    // notice the little fudge to make sure some portion of a line is above the bottom
    BOOL bottom = contentOffsetY + textView.font.lineHeight * 1.5 > contentSize.height - boundsSize.height;

    self.scrollableItem.hidden = !excess || bottom;
}
```

The fudge is due to the fact that view height may not be an integral multiple of the line height for a given font.  A little more than a line seems to do the trick.

Comment: Works like a charm ! Thank you !